# Next Occurance of day and month

Tags: php

I want to be able to find the next occurrence of a date when I give it just the date and month. I have found answers on how to find 'next monday' or how to do this in another language, but I cant figure out how to do it PHP!

For example, if the date I give a function is 2019-07-04 (Y-m-d), on 2019-07-03, the date returned will still be 2019-07-04, but on 2019-07-04, the next occurrence will be 2020-07-04.

So if I give it the date of the 3rd of July, I want to know the next time that date occurs? If its tomorrow or 364 days, just when it comes up next?

Comment: Do you mean add 1 year to the date which you have?

Comment: No because if the date is 3rd of July, the date will be tomorrow, if it is then the 5th of july, it will be 4th of july next year.

Comment: @aynber, at the moment i've not done anything because i'm not sure how to go about it

Comment: what you ask feels like it doesn't make sense. Each day happens once per year. Are you asking, if 3rd of July 2019 is a Wednesday, when's the next time 3rd of July will be a Wednesday?

Comment: I think they want the next occurrence of `07-04` (for example) from the current date.  I think having the year is confusing.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, just the next occurrence of a day and month

Comment: @NigelRen, so If i say 4th July, I just need to get the next 4th of july, so from today it would be 2019-07-04. If todays date was the 5th of july, then the next occurrence would be 2020-07-04.

Comment: PHP has a very full-featured `DateTime` *object* which should be able to do anything you could need – http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php  You are simply "adding one month to" the date you have.  Wrap-around caused by year boundaries is handled automatically.  (See also `DateInterval`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check if the date you have is more than today and keep it, or increase by one year.

```
function nextDate($day, $month){
    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d', $month.'-'.$day);
    $today = new \DateTime();
    if($dateObj > $today){
        return $dateObj;
    }
    return $dateObj->modify('+ 1 year');
}
```

https://ideone.com/Nf9HWh

Comment: I need to be able to pass only the day and month, not the year

Comment: You can modify this to take two parameters.

Comment: Brilliant yes, this is exactly what I needed! Thank you for your help

Comment: You don't need to format the `DateTime` objects to compare them.

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks, in my previous example, I had to format them.

Comment: `nextDate(29, 2)` returns `2019-03-01`.

Answer (score 0):

I've honestly been unable to compose a working [relative format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) for [strtotime()](https://php.net/strtotime), which would be the elegant one-liner we all dream of, so I've composed a poor-man's loop:

```
/**
 * @param int $month
 * @param int $day
 * @param int $reference Unix time, defaults to today
 * @return int Unix time
 */
function nextOcurrence($month, $day, $reference = null)
{
    if ($reference === null) {
        $reference = mktime(0, 0, 0);
    }
    $year = date('Y', $reference);
    while (!checkdate($month, $day, $year) || ($date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year)) <= $reference){
        $year++;
    }
    return $date;
}
```

Highlights:

- "Today" is not hard-coded to ease testing.
- It takes leap years into account but not [Popes fiddling with the calendar](http://mentalfloss.com/article/51370/why-our-calendars-skipped-11-days-1752).
- It uses Unix timestamps so it cannot handle dates prior to 1970 in 32-bit PHP.
- Dates are hard so it's probably wrong.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/O8Ht1).